# getForm() with request body

Tags: html, r, api, request

I have been using for a month or so and I really enjoy it. I'm now a bit struggling when it comes to using the RCurl/XML/JSON packages.

I have 2 separate problems:

1- A web service is published at a specific url and accepts the following HTML queries:

```
<Object_Request>
<id>1253</id>
</Object_Request>
```

How can I embed the id number in my request? Shall I use getURL() or postForm() ?

2- Another test for me is to use the Amara API (here: http://amara.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html)

I tried to use the postForm():

```
postForm(url,.params=c("X-api-username:"=my_user_id,
                   "X-apikey:"=my_code))
```

and I got the following error message:

```
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

Same thing with getURL:

```
getURL(url,httpheader=c("X-api-username:"=my_user_id,
                   "X-apikey:"=my_code) )
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  I've been trying to recreate the following in R http://www.bemasher.net/archives/1002.  I can do everything except for posting to a form.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting `ssl.verifypeer = 1L, ssl.verifyhost = 1L, 
             cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", 
             package = "RCurl")`
in your `getURL` and `postForm` requests.